# Problems with signature when posting to the pionex API

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm currently working on a way to place a buy order on the pionex platform with a Python code so I can use my bot on pionex. Getting information from the pionex API is a successful, but when posting a request to the API to buy some bitcoin I get an error:

> {'result': False, 'timestamp': 1702144786335, 'code': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE', 'message': 'invalid signature'}

My code for getting information from the API is:

```
import requests
import time
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from urllib.parse import urlencode

api_key = "my api key"
api_secret = "my api secret"

# Function to generate the PIONEX-SIGNATURE
def generate_signature(api_secret, method, path, timestamp, params=None, data=None):
    # Set query parameters as key-value pairs: key=value
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    params['timestamp'] = timestamp
    query_string = urlencode(sorted(params.items()))

    # Concatenate query parameters after PATH with ?
    path_url = f"{path}?{query_string}"

    # Concatenate METHOD and PATH_URL
    message = f"{method.upper()}{path_url}"

    # Concatenate related entity body of POST and DELETE after step 5
    if data is not None:
        message += json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))

    print(message)
    # Use API Secret and the above result to generate HMAC SHA256 code, then convert it to hexadecimal
    signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    return signature

def make_private_request(method, endpoint, params=None, data=None):
    url = f"https://api.pionex.com{endpoint}"

    # Get current millisecond timestamp
    timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

    # Set timestamp in params
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    params['timestamp'] = timestamp

    # Set headers
    headers = {
        'PIONEX-KEY': api_key,
        'PIONEX-SIGNATURE': generate_signature(api_secret, method, endpoint, timestamp, params=params, data=data),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    # Make the request
    if method == 'GET':
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    elif method == 'POST':
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, params=params )
    elif method == 'DELETE':
        response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers, json=data, params=params)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported HTTP method: {method}")

    print(f"Generated Signature: {headers['PIONEX-SIGNATURE']}")
    print(f"Generated Message: {method.upper()}{url}?{urlencode(sorted(params.items()))}")
    print(f"Server Timestamp: {response.json().get('timestamp')}")

    return response.json()


endpoint = "/api/v1/trade/order"
order_data = {
    "clientOrderId": "9e3d93d6-e9a4-465a-a39c-2e48568fe194",
    "symbol": "BTC_USDT",
    "side": "BUY",
    "type": "LIMIT",
    "size": "0.1",
    "price": "30000",
    "IOC": True
}

response = make_private_request('GET', '/api/v1/trade/allOrders', params={'symbol': 'BTC_USDT', 'limit': 1})

print(response)
```

my response was:

```
GET/api/v1/trade/allOrders?limit=1&symbol=BTC_USDT&timestamp=1702145234971
Generated Signature: f34cb0064bf618d64181d7b2afb64f24f63872f38eed8f7ee8683c34c6e8a86d
Generated Message: GEThttps://api.pionex.com/api/v1/trade/allOrders?limit=1&symbol=BTC_USDT&timestamp=1702145234971
Server Timestamp: 1702145234500
{'result': True, 'data': {'orders': []}, 'timestamp': 1702145234500}
```

my code for placing a order:

```
import requests
import time
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from urllib.parse import urlencode


api_key = "my api key"
api_secret = "my api secret"


def get_trade_price(api_key, secret_key, symbol):
    # Endpoint voor het verkrijgen van handelsinformatie
    endpoint = 'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/tickers'

    # Parameters voor het verzoek
    params = {
        'symbol': symbol
    }

    # Voeg timestamp en API-sleutel toe aan de parameters
    params['timestamp'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
    params['apiKey'] = api_key

    # Creëer de handtekening (signature) voor het verzoek
    query_string = '&'.join([f"{key}={params[key]}" for key in sorted(params.keys())])
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), query_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    params['signature'] = signature

    # Maak het verzoek naar de Pionex API
    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)

    # Controleer of het verzoek succesvol was (statuscode 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Decodeer de JSON-response
        data = response.json()

        # Controleer de structuur van de ontvangen gegevens
        tickers = data['data']['tickers']
        for ticker in tickers:
            if ticker['symbol'] == symbol:
                # Haal de handelsprijs op
                trade_price = ticker.get('close')

                # Druk de handelsprijs af
                return trade_price
    else:
        print(f"Fout bij het ophalen van de handelsprijs. Statuscode: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)
        return None
# Function to generate the PIONEX-SIGNATURE
def generate_signature(api_secret, method, path, timestamp, params=None, data=None):
    # Set query parameters as key-value pairs: key=value
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    params['timestamp'] = timestamp
    query_string = urlencode(sorted(params.items()))

    # Concatenate query parameters after PATH with ?
    path_url = f"{path}?{query_string}"

    # Concatenate METHOD and PATH_URL
    message = f"{method.upper()}{path_url}"

    # Concatenate related entity body of POST and DELETE after step 5
    if data is not None:
        message += json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))

    print(message)
    # Use API Secret and the above result to generate HMAC SHA256 code, then convert it to hexadecimal
    signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    return signature

def make_private_request(method, endpoint, params=None, data=None, payload=None):
    url = f"https://api.pionex.com{endpoint}"

    # Get current millisecond timestamp
    timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

    # Set timestamp in params
    if params is None:
        params = {}
    params['timestamp'] = timestamp

    # Set headers
    headers = {
        'PIONEX-KEY': api_key,
        'PIONEX-SIGNATURE': generate_signature(api_secret, method, endpoint, timestamp, params=params, data=data),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    # Make the request
    if method == 'GET':
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    elif method == 'POST':
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        response = requests.post(url + f"?timestamp={timestamp}", headers=headers, json=data)
    elif method == 'DELETE':
        response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers, json=data, params=params)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported HTTP method: {method}")

    print(f"Generated Signature: {headers['PIONEX-SIGNATURE']}")
    print(f"Generated Message: {method.upper()}{url}?{urlencode(sorted(params.items()))}")
    print(f"Server Timestamp: {response.json().get('timestamp')}")

    return response.json()

trading_price = get_trade_price(api_key, api_secret, "BTC_USDT")
endpoint = "/api/v1/trade/order"
order_data = {
    "symbol": "BTC_USDT",
}


response = make_private_request('POST', endpoint, data=order_data)


print(response)
```

My response is:

```
POST/api/v1/trade/order?timestamp=1702145331250{"symbol":"BTC_USDT"}
Generated Signature: d404d623898e46ba61d37c86245594f2885a2160cbf401bd1c3ed081a04494af
Generated Message: POSThttps://api.pionex.com/api/v1/trade/order?timestamp=1702145331250
Server Timestamp: 1702145330729
{'result': False, 'timestamp': 1702145330729, 'code': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE', 'message': 'invalid signature'}
```

the link to the api documetation = [pionex api](https://pionex-doc.gitbook.io/apidocs/)
the api key and secret are exactly the same in both codes

I tried place some thing on other places and deleting params, data changing it and I putted extra things but all didn't work. Also I makde the signature generating a few times on a other way. When it all didn't work I asked it and chatgpt and blackbox and still I'm getting the same error. I even when gaved the hole documentation the code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

so after I tried some thing I found where my error was coming from all the time it was 1 space

```
if method.upper() == 'POST' and data is not None:
     message += json.dumps(data, separators=(', ', ': '))
```

it needed to be ", " and ": " instead of "," and ":"